# Automatic assign wordpress category to a post class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

Is it possible to create a function similar to this one

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {  
    global $wpdb;  
    $postsWeWants = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_author FROM $wpdb->posts where ID = $post_ID");  
    foreach ($postsWeWants as $postsWeWant) {  
        if(($postsWeWant->post_author != 30) && ($postsWeWant->post_author != 29) && !in_category('bundle')){  
            $cat = array(9547,9742);  
            wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);  
        }  
    }  
}  
add_action('publish_post', 'add_category_automatically');
```

but based on the [post class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) instead of author and category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that should do the trick:

```
function add_category_by_class($post_ID) {  
  if( in_array( 'classToCheckFor' get_post_class('', $post_ID)) ){
    $cat = array(9547,9742);
    wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true); 
  }       
}  
add_action('publish_post', 'add_category_by_class');
```

Comment: Thanks!! But this takes me to another issue. Do you have any idea why a class appear in firebug but not in <?php post_class(); ?> ?

Comment: could be because it's hardcoded in some template file or added by some hooks, which WP has plenty of... Which class are we talking about?

Comment: This worked thanks : function add_category_by_class( $post_ID ){

            if(isset($_POST['classToCheckFor'])){
      $cat = array(9547,9742);
      wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true); 
        
      }      
}  
add_action('publish_post', 'add_category_by_class');